# How to publish my android app to android market?

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I have developed the android application, now the time is to release my app to android market.
I have gone through many websites tutorial to know how to publish my app. But those things are confused me. So if anyone help me the step by step procedure to publishing the app.

Comment: Simply check this [Link]. In this link all information explained in detail and from scratch I think it will help you. [Link]:http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449383268/ch08_id35815995.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this [put app in market by The New Boston](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1j4prh3NAZE&list=PL34F010EEF9D45FB8&index=199).

Answer (score 4):

Before you can publish, you must register as a developer on android market.  There's a payment associated with this registration (but it's not large).  Go to http://market.android.com/publish to get started.

Also read the publishing sections on the android developer's guide.  The four parts you need are:

- Signing: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html
- Versioning: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html
- Preparing to publish: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html
- Publishing: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

All the information is there - plus a bit of "follow the instructions on screen" during the actual publishing process.

Answer (score 0):

its very easy to publis ionic app for play store , use these simple steps to publish your ionic app for android

step -1 --> configer Your app setting for publish ,like app package name,description and othere information into the config.xml file

step-2 --> you need to add the android platform using this command

$ ionic platform add android

step-3 --> After adding the android platform use this command to generate the unsigned APK

$ cordova build --release android

step-4--> After executing the above command you will get and unsigned APK insde the "platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk"

step-5--> now create a folder in any drive and copy android-release-unsigned.apk file to this foler

step-6--> now you have to generate demo-key.keystore file using this command it will ask app info with org info provide that and don't forget password 
,this password will be use when you will update the Your app later

$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore demo-key.keystore -alias DemoApp -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

step-7--> now use the jarsigner command for signed apk

$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore demo-key.keystore android-release-unsigned.apk DemoApp

step-8--> now use this final command to get signed APK with aligned , if u will get zipalign internal external command error copy zipalign.exe to current folder from C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1

$ zipalign -v 4 android-release-unsigned.apk OlebEvent.apk

Answer (score 0):

**There are step by step given below that you have to follow to pulish your android app to play store,**

**1. - Sign up for a Google Play Developer account.**

- Pay registration fee.
- Complete your account details.

  https://play.google.com/apps/publish

**2. Then folllow given below link to set up account,**

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en

**3. In android studio Generate signed bundle,**

- Go to Build -> Generate Signed Bundle/APK... in Android Studio.
- Select Android App Bundle -> Next

  [image]
- Next enter details as like shown below and click OK -> Next.[image]

  - Enter details as previous and click Nextbutton.
    [image]
  - Select release and click Finish

[image]

- Now, Signed apk(bundle) is ready.

**4. Now go to your google play developer console**

- Click 'Create Application'
- Select a default language and add a title for your app. Type the name of your app as 
  you want it to appear on Google Play.
- Create your app's store listing,

  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/188189
- Take the content rating questionnaire,

  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/188189 
  and set up
- Set up pricing and distribution.

  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373
- Now, Create a release

  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011?hl=en
- Prepare your app's release
- Review and start roll out your release

**# With in maximum 7 days your application will be live**